# vimrc not accepting mouse-=a command

Tags: vim

I have strange problem with my `/etc/vim/vimrc` file.

I was trying to get rid of VISUAL mode in VIM, so I have tried to add the `set mouse-=a` command in my `vimrc` file.

However my vim does not take those changes into account.

When I do `:set mouse-=a` in openend vim, it does what I want (selecting text with mouse without entering VISUAL mode), but the command does not work in the `vimrc` file.

I have also enabled the "jump to the last position when reopening a file" in `vimrc` and it is working, that makes me even more confused.
I have been trying every possible command:

- `set mouse=a`
- `set mouse=r`
- `set mouse-=a`
- `:set mouse-=a`

None of them is working when added to `/etc/vim/vimrc`.

My system is:

```
rRr-kali:~# uname -a
Linux rRr-kali 4.8.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.15-1kali1 (2016-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
rRr-kali:~#
```

Comment: Are you sure your vimrc is being loaded? Try to put `echo "vimrc loaded"` at the end of your vimrc and see if you get this message when you open Vim. Also, where did you get the idea of the `-` in `set mouse-=a`?

Comment: Run `:verbose set mouse?` (with the question mark) and it will tell you where your configuration is being overridden.

Comment: `/etc/vim/vimrc` is **not** your `vimrc`. It's the system `vimrc` and you, as a mere user, have no business editing it. Use `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know, that this question is a bit old, but I just want to clarify, why both answers above are correct and why it's working that way.

On Debian systems the way the config files for vim are loaded is like this:

1. Load settings in `/etc/vim/vimrc`
2. If exists, load settings from `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`
3. If `~/.vimrc` does not exist and there is no `"let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1"` in `/etc/vim/vimrc` or `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`, load settings from `/usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim` otherwise load settings from `~/.vimrc` (if it exists).

Details for that can be found in the config files itself, as well as in a discussion on [bugs.debian.org](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=864074)

So to **solve your issue** you have two ways to go:

1. Insert `"let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1"` at the beginning of `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`.
2. Create an empty `~/.vimrc` by issuing `touch ~/.vimrc`.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=864074

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Debian 9 (Strecth), edit the file /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim and change the line 70 to put

```
set mouse-=a
```

Best Regards

Thibault

Comment: On Debian 10 it's line 79 in /usr/share/vim/vim81/defaults.vim

Comment: this is the incisive answer, ty.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `mouse-=a` to the end of ~/.vimrc resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

At least at RaspberryOS (Debian) the "problem" is that */usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim* will be executed after */etc/vim/vimrc* (including *vimrc.local*) or *~/.vimrc*

Thus I changed line *defaults.vim* alike this:

```
 69  if has('mouse')
 70          if empty("+mouse")
 71                  set mouse=a
 72          endif
 73  endif
```

now I'm able to *set mouse-=a* in system wide or personal *vimrc*