# vim not accepting mouse=a and unable to scroll

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vim, debian

I'm using a Debian 11 VM on Google Cloud. I cannot get `set mouse=a` to work, and I can't scroll when I open any file with vim.

I have already seen [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389107/vimrc-not-accepting-mouse-a-command) and have tried everything suggested, but it doesn't work still.

I have have an extensive `.vimrc` (and also have tried a pared down minimal version). I've tried editing the `defaults.vim` in `/usr/share/vim` as well the `.vimrc` in `etc/vim`. I've tried toggling with `set compatible` and `set nocompatible` as well as adding `let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1`

What can I fix it? I'd just like to scroll and use my mouse.

Comment: `mouse=a` and `mouse-=a` are opposites. Which one are you using?

Comment: mouse = a.

Should I be using mouse-=a?

Comment: Are you using SSH to connect to the VM? If yes, mouse events are not forwarded via an SSH session. You would need to use a desktop GUI protocol. Example VNC.

Comment: Yes I'm using SSH. Are you saying my VM's local `.vimrc` won't work?

Comment: No, I am saying that Vim will not receive mouse events. It does not matter how you configure `.vimrc` to process mouse events if it cannot receive any.

Comment: Ohh okay. Any solutions?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my first comment, use a desktop protocol such as VNC. There are several good ones. However, getting everything set up (Desktop GUI, VM configuration, VNC) is complicated. Look for a good tutorial.

Comment: @JohnHanley "*…mouse events are not forwarded via an SSH session.*" Not true. I have a lot of remote servers to which I SSH from my local notebook and where I run console `vim`; mouse works. The trick is that I have X11 desktop locally and run SSH in `xterm` (`rxvt` to be precise); they pass click and scroll events over SSH and remote `vim` receives those events, no problem. Console mouse events OTOH are not propagated via SSH, that's for sure.

Comment: @thorium What desktop do you have locally? If you have XWin you don't need VNC. On the server side uninstall `vim-tiny` and install `vim`, on the local side run a terminal, in it run `ssh server` — they should pass mouse events.

Comment: @phd - you are correct for your environment because you setup additional software. In Google Cloud, there is no desktop. You have to jump through hoops to create one. As I mentioned in my comment, he needs a desktop GUI protocol to forward mouse events.

Comment: @JohnHanley On the server side there is no need for a desktop, just a X11-aware `vim`. In Debian default `vim` is `vim-tiny` which is not X11-aware. It needs to be replaced with X11-aware `vim`. `sudo apt uninstall -y vim-tiny && sudo apt install -y vim`

Comment: @phd - Have you tested that on Google Cloud VMs? If your solution is correct for Google Cloud, thank you. However, knowing the Google Cloud Compute Engine protocols, I have my doubts. The ssh client used by GCP has no mouse support. You would then need to bypass features such as OSLogin and configure your own tools. I will test this to learn more.

Comment: In Vim, calling `:echo has('mouse')` will show a `1` if you have mouse support. If it's `0`, you need to install a more full-featured version of Vim as pointed out by phd.

Comment: I use a Mac locally, and currently just use the `SSH` button on GCP to login, I don't use my local terminal. @phd are you saying that if I install a X11 aware vim my problems should be resolved? Running `:echo has ('mouse')` does show a `1` - so my Debian has some mouse awareness?

Comment: @JohnHanley Standard OpenSSH client and server also don't have any mouse support. Mouse events are ANSI codes, SSH just passes them transparently. No, I've never worked with GCP, but I do not expect any problems.

Comment: Google Cloud VMs do not have X11 configured, nor frame buffers, mouse support, etc. The default OS configuration is SSH command line only.

Comment: @thorium I don't know if it's possible to pass X11 mouse over SSH outside of terminal. It must be a job for GCP terminal but I know nothing about it.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, all my servers are like that — no X11, nor frame buffers, only SSH server `sshd`. It's enough.

Comment: Okay so as I understand it I have two options:
- Try `vim` instead of `vim-tiny`, have X11 on my local machine and then use my terminal to SSH into the VM?

OR (if that fails)

- use a Desktop GUI protocol such as VNC?

Comment: @thorium Yep, I think these two are the only alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

As per solution of [Bernhard Laven](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318824/vim-cutpaste-not-working-in-stretch-debian-9), preferably you can configure global configuration with your instance /etc/vim/vimrc.local that can take effect within the instance.

See sample configuration file for `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` :

```
" This file loads the default vim options at the beginning and prevents
" that they are being loaded again later. All other options that will be set,
" are added, or overwrite the default settings. Add as many options as you
" whish at the end of this file.

" Load the defaults
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim

" Prevent the defaults from being loaded again later, if the user doesn't
" have a local vimrc (~/.vimrc)
let skip_defaults_vim = 1


" Set more options (overwrites settings from /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim)
" Add as many options as you whish

" Set the mouse mode to 'r'
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=r
endif
```

As added information, there can be an issue or bug with the /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim see [link](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=864074). which is also available with his solution.